# Placing the caret in an previous editable div and pressing enter should re-evaluate that input

Tags: javascript, html

I have this online code execution editable div that currently works step by step by using a function called parse. You input something (for example 7+5) and press enter and you get the result on a new line below and a new input div is created but if you go back to an previous editable input div and put in a new input and press enter it does not work correctly because a new output and input divs are created by default and the new code is not being re-evaluated.

Note that if you put in a : at the end of input in an input box (editable div) then no new output div is created. Output is hidden from view. This is by design to avoid long outputs that does not need to be displayed.

I have also tried to write a new function parse2() but then the step by step evaluation stops working. It appears to be very hard to get both (step by step and go back to old editable div and re-evaluate) to work at the same time. How can this be done? I think I need some if statement in function parse() that determines if it is new input code that being executed or old input code that being re-evaluated. I have also tried to assign a number to the input divs but I have not managed to get that to work.

```
 function parse2(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
 event.preventDefault();

 if (document.getElementById("output") == null) {
  CreateOutputDiv();
  CreateInputDiv(); 
  // calculates and assign values to output div 
  var d1 = document.getElementById(JSON.stringify(input)).innerText; 
  console.log("in = " + d1); 
  var d2 = eval(d1);
  console.log("out = " + d2);
  output.innerHTML = d2;
  document.getElementById("count").value += '\n' + '\n' + cc;     
  } else if { //re-evaluates inputbox = works
  var d1 = document.getElementById(JSON.stringify(input)).innerText;  
  console.log("new in = " + d1); 
  var d2 = eval(d1);
  console.log("new out = " + d2);
  output.innerHTML = d2; 
  input.focus();
   }  else { //re-evaluates inputbox = works
  CreateOutputDiv();
  var d1 = document.getElementById(JSON.stringify(input)).innerText;  
  console.log("new in = " + d1); 
  var d2 = eval(d1);
  console.log("new out = " + d2);
  output.innerHTML = d2; 
  input.focus(); }}}
```

**JavaS.js and HTML below**

```js
// counts the number of input divs created
function increment() {
  increment.n = increment.n || 0;
  return ++increment.n;
}

// creates an input div
function CreateInputDiv() {
  increment();
  cc = increment.n;
  console.log("increment.n = " + cc);

  input = document.createElement("div");
  input.setAttribute("id", "input");
  input.setAttribute("class", "input");
  input.innerHTML = "&nbsp";
  input.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
  input.setAttribute("onkeypress", "parse(event, this)");
  document.getElementById('calc').appendChild(input);
  input.focus();
}

// creates an output div 
function CreateOutputDiv() {
  output = document.createElement("div");
  output.setAttribute("id", "output");
  output.setAttribute("class", "output");
  output.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
  output.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
  document.getElementById('calc').appendChild(output);
}


function parse(e) {
  var key = window.event.keyCode;

  if (key == 13) { //keycode for enter 
    event.preventDefault();

    var inz = input.innerText;

    // check if input contains a colon. Hides output if colon exist. 
    if (inz.indexOf(':') > -1) {
     // colon 
      var inz = input.innerText.replace(/:/g, '');
      console.log("input without colon = " + inz);
      var outz = eval(inz);
      console.log("out = " + outz);
      document.getElementById("count").value += '\n' + eval(cc + 1);
      CreateInputDiv();
    }
    else {
      // no colon = display output
      // counter 
      document.getElementById("count").value += '\n' + '\n' + eval(cc + 1);

      // create output div 
      CreateOutputDiv(); 

      // calculate and assign output value to output div  
      console.log("input = " + inz);
      var outz = eval(inz);
      console.log("out = " + outz);
      output.innerHTML = outz;

      // creates a new input div
      CreateInputDiv();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaS.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
      div:focus {
      background-color: lightpink;
    }
  .input {
      background-color: lightgreen;
      width: 980px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      resize: none;
      overflow: auto;
      overflow-wrap: break-word; 
    }
    .output {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 980px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      resize: none;
      overflow-wrap: break-word; 
    }
   #count {
      background-color: lightblue;
      color: black;
      width: 25px;
      height: 650px;
      font-size: 17px;
      resize: none;
      overflow: auto;
      border: none;              
    }
#calc{
background-color:lightblue;
overflow: scroll;
vertical-align: top; 
border: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="grey">
<table align="center" width="1000px" height="650px" bgcolor="lightblue">
    <tr>
        <td><textarea id="count" disabled>1 </textarea> </td>
        <td id = "calc"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
 
  <script>   CreateInputDiv();   </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating new input and output divs, you are applying the same id to all inputs and outputs.  Instead of which you can use your counter number 'cc' to give all unique ids.  Then when you call your parse function, you already are supplying parameter 'this' to it.  Use 'this' to get element by id.  And if the div with this output id is already present, just alter its content, otherwise create a new one.

```
    <script>
    // counts the number of input divs created
    function increment() {
      increment.n = increment.n || 0;
      return ++increment.n;
    }

    // creates an input div
    function CreateInputDiv() {
      increment();
      cc = increment.n;
      //console.log("increment.n = " + cc);

      input = document.createElement("div");
      input.setAttribute("id", "input"+cc);
      input.setAttribute("class", "input");
      input.innerHTML = "&nbsp";
      input.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
      input.setAttribute("onkeypress", "parse(event, this)");
      document.getElementById('calc').appendChild(input);
      input.focus();
    }

    // creates an output div 
    function CreateOutputDiv() {
      output = document.createElement("div");
      output.setAttribute("id", "output"+cc);
      output.setAttribute("class", "output");
      output.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
      output.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
      document.getElementById('calc').appendChild(output);
    }


    function parse(e,e2) {
        //console.log(e2);
      var key = window.event.keyCode;

      if (key == 13) { //keycode for enter 
        event.preventDefault();    
        //console.log(e2.id);
        var inId = e2.id;
        var outId = "output"+ inId.substring(5);
        //console.log(outId);

        var inz = input.innerText;

        // check if input contains a colon. Hides output if colon exist. 
        if (inz.indexOf(':') > -1) {
         // colon 
          var inz = input.innerText.replace(/:/g, '');
          //console.log("input without colon = " + inz);
          var outz = eval(inz);
          //console.log("out = " + outz);
          document.getElementById("count").value += '\n' + eval(cc + 1);
          CreateInputDiv();
        }
        else {
          // no colon = display output
          // counter 
          if(document.getElementById(outId)) {
              console.log("Already created");
              inz = document.getElementById(inId).innerText;
              console.log(inz);
              var outz = eval(inz);

              document.getElementById(outId).innerHTML = outz;

          } 
          else {
                document.getElementById("count").value += '\n' + '\n' + eval(cc + 1);
                // create output div 
                CreateOutputDiv(); 

                // calculate and assign output value to output div  
                //console.log("input = " + inz);
                var outz = eval(inz);
                //console.log("out = " + outz);
                output.innerHTML = outz;

                // creates a new input div
                CreateInputDiv();          
          }
        }
      }
    }

   </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for that code and for helping me. The code works very well. You saved me from a lot of headache and having to wasting time on countless hours of trial and error.